# Initializing @attr in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive like this:
you can see the equivalent plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/0e2nMyatAMD3M3QTCtls

```
app.directive('bpTest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'directiveTemplate.html',
    scope: {
      bpType: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
      console.log($scope, $elem, $attrs);
      $scope.bpType = $scope.bpType || 'text';
    }  // link function
  };
});
```

In directiveTemplate.html:

```
<div>
  {{ bpType }}
</div>
```

In index.html:

```
<div bp-test bp-type="text"></div>  <!-- results in <div>text</div> -->
<div bp-test bp-type="number"></div>  <!-- results in <div>number</div> -->
<div bp-test></div>  <!-- results in <div></div> ????? -->
```

Since I initialize `$scope.bpType = $scope.bpType || 'text'`, I expect the third directive `<div bp-test></div>` to display `<div>text</div>` but it just spits out `<div></div>`.

What am I misunderstanding/doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope binding happens later than the first call to your link function so you need to watch the attribute to set your default value.

```
$scope.$watch("bpType", function(value) {
  $scope.bpType = value || 'default';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link function should look like:

```js
scope: {  
},
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.bpType = attrs.bpType || 'text';
}
```

Notice $attrs.bpType not $scope.bpType
Additionally parameters in link function by convention should not be named with $prefix as those are function parameters, not injected dependencies.